# Why stepper motor is slow with A4988 driver?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, cnc

I'm using NEMA17 17HS13-0404S1 stepper motors with Arduino CNC Shield & A4988 drivers but I think they're much slower than they should be. Hard to explain how slow they are but compared to Ender 3 Pro 3d printer, they move slow. And also I checked some other step motors from Youtube, seems slow compared to them too.

Here you can find the data of my stepper motor: https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-17-bipolar-1-8deg-26ncm-36-8oz-in-0-4a-12v-42x42x34mm-4-wires.html

I set A4988 Vref to 0.30V (calculated is 0.32 but for 10% margin recommendation, I set it to 0.30) and I'm using 1/16 microstepping.

As power supply, I use 24V, 4.5A power supply and connected it to CNC shield directly (which powers A4988s)

What might be wrong about my stepper motors?

Comment: how fast are you driving it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm not sure about how can I measure it, mm/sec?

Comment: Were you using 1/16 microstepping with your previous driver?

Comment: @evildemonic I didn't use any other driver but I guess my 3d printer uses 1/16 too.

Comment: Those drivers are pretty simple: 1 pulse = 1 microstep ... so either your pulses are coming in too slow, or you are using a higher fraction of microstepping than you realize.

Comment: @shehatesme, you do not measure rotational speed (angular velocity) in mm/s ... if you want to measure how fast something turns, you can use a stopwatch to measure a 100 revolutions

Comment: How many steps/second are you driving it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond not very accurate but I counted down with a timer and motor made approximately 12.5 full turns in a minute (without any belt etc. load on it). So it's around 2500 steps/min and 40-42 steps in a second.

Comment: If you're microstepping that's 640 microsteps/second. What's your software doing? So far there's no evidence at all that there's anything wrong.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you, so if i reduce microsteps will it be much faster? I use it with grbl/cnc shield, it’s a laser engraver...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I tried disabling microstepping and with full steps, it's doing 12.5 full turns in a minute too and vibrates too much. Do you think that's also correct behaviour?

Comment: For example, here OpenBuilds steppers are moving much faster and smoother than my steppers: https://youtu.be/GrjqW2MDCvM?t=3744 What can be the difference?

Comment: And here is the datasheet for their steppers: https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-itwgldve/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/105/3714/imgpsh_fullsize_4__22403.1539714162.jpg?c=2?imbypass=on

Comment: Consider how your software drives the motors.